# org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException : getting this error while making an api call

Tags: httpclient

getting This error while using the rest template

this is my pooling configuration

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws SFSManagerException {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(0);
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(500);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
            .custom()
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000) // timeout to get connection from pool
            .setSocketTimeout(30000) // standard connection timeout 
            .setConnectTimeout(5000) // standard connection timeout
            .build();
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
private ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy() {
    return new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
        @Override
        public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
            HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator
                (response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
                String param = he.getName();
                String value = he.getValue();
                if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase
                   ("timeout")) {
                    return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
                }
            }
            return 5L * 1000L;
        }
    };
}
```

is there a way we can replicate this in local , I am using apache httpclient 4.5.13 version